# How can I interpolate literal escape sequences with the substitution operator?

Tags: perl

This code:

```
my $st = "37a64";
my $grep = '\n';
$st =~ s/a/$grep/;
print $st;
```

Prints:

```
37\n64
```

I would like to see the following output:

```
37
64
```

But I can only modify the `\n` and regex options because I'm importing `$st` from another file.

Comment: All you need to do is put double quotes around `\n`...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of an existing module to do that.

```
my %tr = (
   n => "\n",
   r => "\r",
   t => "\t",
   # ...
);

$grep =~ s{\\(?:(\W)|(.))}{
   defined($1) ? $1 :
   defined($tr{$2}) ? $tr{$2} :
   do { warn("Unrecognized escapes \\$2"); "\\$2" }
}seg;
```

Please avoid any recommendation to pass inputs to `eval EXPR` (sometimes dangerously disguised as `s///ee`). They are surely buggy and dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `/ee` modifier to evaluate the replacement:

```
$st =~ s/a/qq("$grep")/ee;
```

To understand its function, try

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };


my @st = ("37a64") x 3;
my $grep = '\n';

$st[0] =~ s/a/qq("$grep")/;
say $st[0];                   # 37qq("\n")64


$st[1] =~ s/a/qq("$grep")/e;
say $st[1];                   # 37"\n"64

$st[2] =~ s/a/qq("$grep")/ee;
say $st[2];                   # 37
                              # 64
```

Comment: Why `/ee` rather than `/e`?

Comment: @KeithThompson: Because `/e` doesn't work :-) Check the update.